# HTML, CSS, I dont know whats wrong with my code

Tags: php, html, css

I don't know what wrong with my code but it wont display the position i want.

Here's the output:

[Output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC8I2.jpg)

And here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Escapade Travel & Tours</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Google Fonts-->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Duru+Sans|Actor' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link href="css/bootshape.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigation bar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.html"><span class="green">Escapade</span> Travel & Tours</a>
      </div>
      <nav role="navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="Home.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Destination <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Boracay</a>
              </li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Palawan</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Cebu</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">All Destinations</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="SpecialOffers.html">Special Offers</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="BookNow.html">Book Now!</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Navigation bar -->

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div style="clear: both; height:40px;"></div>
    <div style="clear: both; height:15px;"></div>
    <div style="clear: both; height:15px;"></div>

    <div id="cont_razd">
      <div id="right">
        <h1>Meet Us</h1>
        <div style="height:15px;"></div>
        <div class="box_us">
          <div class="box_us_r">
            <img src="img/fish_us1.gif">&nbsp; Quezon City, Philippines</div>
          <div style="clear: both; height:15px;"></div>
          <p>
            <img src="img/fish_us2.gif">&nbsp; &nbsp;Telephone: 02-1234567</p>
          <div style="clear: both; height:15px;">
            <p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Cellphone: 0912-345-6789</p>
            <div style="clear: both; height:15px;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box_us">
          <div class="box_us_l"></div>
          <div class="box_us_r">
            <div class="box_us_r">
              <div style="clear: both; height:15px;"></div>
              <img src="img/fish_us3.gif" alt="" />&nbsp; Email Add: escapadetravelandtours@yahoo.com</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box_us">
        </div>
        <div style="height:25px;"></div>
        <b> <i> Book us now and get very good rates! :) </b> 
        </i>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div id="left">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <div style="clear: both; height:15px;"></div>
        <?php echo "<form action=" " method="post ">
         <b> Name: </b> <br>
         <input type=text size=40 name="ContactName ">
         <br> <br> <b> E-mail Address: </b> <br> 
         <input type=text size=40 name="ContactEmail ">
         <br> <br> <b> Subject: </b> <br>
         <input type=text size=40 name="ContactSubject ">
         <br> <br> <b> Message: </b> <br>
         <textarea cols=40 rows=5 input type=text size=150 name="ContactMessage "> </textarea>
         <br> <br> 
         <input type="Submit " name="Send "  value="Send ">
         <input type="Reset " name="Reset "  value="Reset ">" ?>

        <div style="clear: both"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <!-- End Content -->

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer text-center">
    <p>&copy; 2016. All Rights Reserved. Created by</p>
  </div>

  <!-- End Footer -->

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootshape.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the meet us to be place in the right while the contact us is in the left but it wont place to where i indicate them.

I have put `<div id="right">` in meets us and `<div id="left">` in contact us.

I'm using notepad ++ here.

[This is my expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxbmA.jpg)

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: this is based on css, post your css here at least some relevant things, like #left and #right.

Comment: the syntax seems quite weird on your last echo... https://3v4l.org/uRefC

Comment: Oh your right, gonna fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
   right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css will make as per your expected result:

```
#left {
    float: left;
}
#right {
    float: right;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qhg847b/)**

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap girds see example of [bootstrap girds](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) also

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-9">
   Your Left content
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3">
   Your right content
   </div>
</div>
```

the easiest way, while you use Bootstrap..

Answer (score 0):

You have included bootstrap anyway in your code.. So you can use the bootstrap class.

```
<div class="row>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
<!-- Put your contact Us div here -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
<!-- Put your meet Us div here -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mentioning `col-xs-12` is not required, until and unless you wanted grids to be side by side. If don't mention, by default it column 12 in all screens, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
div id = "right"
```

does not place your div to the right, it just gives it an id.
Enclose both the divs in a

```
div class = "row"
```

and then the child divs using column span.

Learn about the bootstrap grid system here:-

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 0):

Put the "Contact Us" `div` before the "Meet Us" `div`. Then Apply `float:left;` to both the element. Try to avoid `float:right;` as much as possible.

Otherwise you can use use `display:inline-block` to both the `div`s. Will work just like float and on top of that you can even align them vertically.